# curl query with mongo db

Tags: php, mongodb, curl

I am attempting a number of things, experimenting and trying to return values from a `Mongo DB` used in Appery in my site using `CURL`.

I get a returned result, however, I ONLY want the `STP` field. From what I have read up the code below SHOULD be giving me this, however its not. I ALSO want the result ONLY where the AuditorName field is `NOT NULL`. I am getting the complete recordset though.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
$region = "EGOLI";
$ch = curl_init();
$qry_str = urlencode('{"Region": "'.$region.'"}');
$ecount = urlencode('{"AuditorName":{$ne:null}},{ STP:1, Region: 0, SalesDistrict: 0, OutletName: 0, LicenceNo: 0, OwnerName: 0, OwnerCell: 0, TVPhotoBack: 0, TVPhotoFront: 0, TVPhotoWorking:0, OwnerDocPhoto:0, OutletFront:0, OutletFacia :0, Comments:0, approved:0, sabcomments:0}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.appery.io/rest/1/db/collections/Reach?where='.$qry_str.'&'.$ecount.'&limit=1000');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Appery-Database-Id: 57xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx83','Content-type: application/json'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
$outletlist = $result;
```